# pointwise convergence of polynomials of degree 2 with 2 real roots to $x^2+1$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, uniform-convergence

In some problem, I thought I need to prove the following subproblem :

> Let $\{p_n(x)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of polynomials of degree 2 which converges to $p(x)=x^2+1$ point by point, i.e for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
>    Assume that each $p_n(x)$ has 2 real roots, not necessarily distinct. Prove that this is a contradiction !

From this point, is there any generalization to this problem ?

If we prove that this convergence is *uniform*, we're almost done ! I mean, you can construct a fine tube around $x^2+1$ which protects it from all $p_n(x)$s, because $x^2+1$ never meets *x-axis*.

One problem here, is that *norm* of these sequence may not be bounded over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Can you show the shaded statement? Or are you asking for a generalization to the above?

Comment: @nayrb, before generalization, I've not still proven that contradiction !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: write $p_n(x) = a_n x^2 + b_n x + c_n$. Evaluate at different points (*e.g.* $x=0, 1, -1$). What do you deduce for the coefficients as $n\to\infty$ ?

This generalizes readily to a sequence of degree $m$ polynomials $(p_n(x))$ converging to a fixed degree $m$ polynomial.

Comment: this yields $a_n\rightarrow1,b_n\rightarrow0,c_n\rightarrow1$. Now we have 
$$|p_n(x)-(x^2+1)|\leq |a_n-1|x^2 + |b_n|x^2+|c_n-1|$$
And therefore, for any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, this convergence is uniformly. Did you mean this ?

Comment: Well you want to show that $p_n(x)$ doesn't vanish, so rather write that for all large enough $n$, you have $a_n\geq 0.9$, $|b_n|\leq 0.1$, and $c_n\geq 0.9$. That tells you that $p_n(x) \geq 0.9(x^2+1) - 0.1|x|$. Can that vanish ?

Comment: Thanks, it's a contradiction ! My problem is now done! Now, can we say that such $p_n(x)$ converges to some $p(x)$ uniformly over $\mathbb{R}$ whenever is converges pointwisely ?!

Comment: It doesn't necessarily converge uniformly ! But it does on every compact set.